# How to include package.json using serverless deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am using webpack and serverless to deploy to aws lambda. So far I have been able to configure it to bundle all dependencies into one ts file, but aws complains there is no package.json. So, I found a way to upload the node modules folder as well, which also brought in the package.json but since I am on windows the aws instances don't like the libraries.

How do I include package.json when I run the serverless package or deploy commands so that aws lambda can run the install?

```
include:
      - package.json
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Serverless Webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) plugin, you should be able to get whatever native modules you need installed by using the `packagerOptions` config for the plugin and specifying the linux platform for x64 architecture along with the list of npm modules to package.

See the [Custom scripts](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#custom-scripts) section of the plugin's documentation for more info.

For example, if your Lambda function depends on the `sharp` npm package, you'd add something like the following to your `serverless.yml` file:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules: true
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - npm_config_platform=linux npm_config_arch=x64 yarn add sharp
```